# PMCMD Stop workflow

Tags: powershell, informatica-powercenter

Hi i am trying to stop workflow through PMCMD but unsuccessfully.
i am doing it through powershell

```
&"$INFS_ROOT\pmcmd.exe" stopworkflow -usd DS -u $IFPC_USER -p $IFPC_PASS -sv ISUD -d DomainIF -f ("$Folder") ("$wf");
```

But everytime i got error:

> ERROR: Option value cannot start with one leading '-'. Usage: pmcmd
>
> stopworkflow
>                             <<-service|-sv> service <-domain|-d> domain [<-timeout|-t> timeout]>
>                             [<<-user|-u> username|<-uservar|-uv> userEnvVar>]
>                             [<<-password|-p> password|<-passwordvar|-pv> passwordEnvVar>]
>                             [<<-usersecuritydomain|-usd> usersecuritydomain|<-usersecuritydomainvar|-usdv> userSecuritydomainEnvVar>]
>                             [<-folder|-f> folder] [<-runinsname|-rin> runInsName]
>                             [-wfrunid workflowRunId] [-wait|-nowait] workflow

For example getworkflowstatus works clear

```
&"$INFS_ROOT\pmcmd.exe"  getworkflowdetails -usd DS -u $IFPCUser -p $IFPCPass -sv ISUD -d DomainIF -f ("$Folder") ("$wf")
```

Can anyone help me with stopping workflow through pmcmd? Thanks

Comment: One of the arguments is invalid. To double-check the values, use `write-host` to print the command instead of invoking `&` it.

Comment: According to [KB 103421](https://kb.informatica.com/solution/11/Pages/103421.aspx) this error means that one of the mandatory options is not provided. Did you try to use `-wfrunid`?

Comment: The example commands use different $IFP... variables. Do they contain identical values?